# What kind of node connects to your full node and doesn't share blocks with you?

Tags: network, peers

When running `getpeerinfo` I can see that a number of connected nodes return a `synced_blocks` of **-1**.

Some of these have been connected for days, so:

1. Is it correct to assume that these nodes are never attempting to propagate blocks around the network?
2. If so, what's their purpose if they're not propagating block data around the network?

You can see what I mean here: http://learnmeabitcoin.com/explorer/node/

Answer (score 2):

It could be a blockchain analysis node of some sort (eg. Chainalysis or similar), or it could be [a pseudonode](https://github.com/basil00/PseudoNode).